# ¿Como solucionar el error de Python dejo de funcionar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Buen día, primero que nada incluiré la imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar es un error típico de Windows, el problema está en que no tengo la más remota idea de que lo ocasiona. Estoy utilizando python en su version **3.8.10** puesto que es la ultima version que puedo utilizar en Windows 7 de **32 bits.**
Estoy intentando ejecutar un archivo .py con el siguiente contenido

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Función que implementa el algoritmo de ordenamiento por selección
def selection_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if arr[j] < arr[min_idx]:
                min_idx = j
        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]

# Lectura de números enteros desde un archivo externo
filename = "numeros.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    numeros = [int(x) for x in f.readlines()]

# Inicio del temporizador
start_time = time.time()

# Ordenamiento de los números utilizando el algoritmo de selección
selection_sort(numeros)

# Fin del temporizador
end_time = time.time()

# Cálculo del tiempo de ejecución del algoritmo
tiempo_ejecucion = end_time - start_time

# Impresión del tiempo de ejecución del algoritmo
print("Tiempo de ejecución:", tiempo_ejecucion)

# Gráfica de línea que muestra el tiempo de ejecución del algoritmo
plt.plot([1], [tiempo_ejecucion], 'ro')
plt.ylabel('Tiempo de ejecución (segundos)')
plt.xlabel('Número de elementos')
plt.title('Tiempo de ejecución del algoritmo de selección')
plt.show()
```

Tengo la libreria matplotlib instalada y el archivo **numeros.txt** en el mismo directorio del archivo .py

Le pase el archivo .py a una compañera que pudo ejecutarlo sin problemas en su computador donde tiene python en su version **3.11.3**

Alguna idea de que podría hacer en mi caso? Cambiar de computador ahora se me hace imposible.

Gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Qué sale en Detalles del problema? Qué sale en los logs de VSC? Qué sale en el visor de eventos de windows?

Comment: No aparece ninguna clase de error ni en los logs de VCS ni en la consola, al parecer es un error de compatibilidad con python.exe o algo por el estilo. Estoy sospechando que es debido a la antiguedad de mi SO

Comment: El revisar los detalles del problema con Windows aparece un error con el arhivo _multiarray_umath.cp311-win32.pyd